# Clear text printed on the Command Line with Java

Tags: java, cmd

How I can clear text that prints in command line with Java? I want to clear `Text1` after prints and overwrite with `Text2`. I search and find this code but it don't work.

```
public class className {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Text1");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
        System.out.println("Text2");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read this http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html and this http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

Comment: This is not possible.  System.out is ***not*** a terminal, it is just an output stream.

Comment: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)

Comment: Most terminal support VT100 commands. You can try to use them. [VT-100 commands](http://www.braun-home.net/michael/info/misc/VT100_commands.htm)

Comment: Most solutions are system dependent and problematic. Perhaps there are other options? Why do you want to clear the output in the first place?

Comment: @Axel I want to create a animated text in command line, so I try to clean previous position of text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with printing `\b`:

```
System.out.print("Text1");
System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b");
System.out.print("     ");
```

Note that this will not work in [Eclipse Console](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936).

Comment: Sorry, a forgot one thing. `\b` just returns cursor one place back, so you need just to print spaces in it. I tested this in windows cmd and it works. Notice I used `print` not `println`!

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

I'm using Windows 8 and this solution worked for me. Hope it does to you as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use '\r'  (carriage return) escape sequence.

```
System.out.print("Text1");
System.out.print("\rText2");
```

Would only print 'Text2'