# How to write a text on the same line with the entered command?

Tags: java

How to write a text on the same line with the entered command before pressing the return-key? I have a switch statement where I choose one command, in this case to write some text after I enter in command "message". It should look like this:

```
  Command> message This is the message!
```

But instead of that, it looks like this:

```
  Command> message 
  This is the message!
```

My code:

```
switch (choice) {
//other commands 

  case "message":
            printMessage();
            break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Error, invalid input!");

}

public void printMessage() {
    String message = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Please be merciful, I'm a complete beginner :)

Comment: can you show the code that you use to read the string from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068783/java-how-to-print-output-to-previous-line-after-input/45069499

Comment: `System.out.println("Choose one number: \n1: Add event \n2: Add       participant \n3: Remove participant \n4: Add result \n5: List results for participants \n6: List results for events \n7: Message \n8: Exit");
                                                                                       String choice = normalize(scan.nextLine().trim());`

Comment: Did you try looking at the question i linked? I think it should work for you

Comment: I did, but didn't work for me :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use the `print()` function instead of the `println()` which prints it on a new line. Here, try this:

```
switch (choice) {
    //other commands 

  case "message":
            printMessage();
            break;
  default:
    System.out.print("Error, invalid input!");

}

public void printMessage() {
    String message = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: i think println() will print and then terminate with a newline character. The problem is not the newline after, it is the newline that the user created when pressing "enter" when he entered the input

Comment: @abiudrn , print() instead of println() was the first thing that I tried but it didn't work. As Thijs Steel says, the problem is the newline that the user creates when pressing "enter".